# match elements in same position of 2 arrays in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, compare, equals, match

I have 2 arrays

```
    @a = qw/ A B C D E     /;
    @b = qw/ B B C       A /;
```

I need to check if the same element appear in the same position of each array

```
    e.g. 

    $a[2] = "B";
    $b[3] = "C";
```

if so count the number of times this happened
it need to **disregard** any blank elements

```
    e.g.

    $a[6] =  ;
    $b[6] =  ;
```

comments are most appreciated I like to understand the script.

I tried intersect eq == cmp etc but I can't quite get it and not quite sure

Thanks in advance.

Here's my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my @a = <FILE1>;
my @b = <FILE2>;

$occurs = 0; #Using eq
foreach my $letter (@a) {
    if (my $letter2 (@a) eq $letter) { #Syntax error here
        $count ++;
    }
} #syntax error here
```

Comment: Please post the code you tried and explain precisely what doesn't work with it.

Comment: <pre>#!/usr/bin/perl -w
my @a = ("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", " ", " ",);
my @b = ("B", "B", "C", " ", " ", "A");


$occurs = 0;

#Using eq
foreach my $letter (@a){

 if (my $letter2 (@a) eq $letter) { #Syntax error here
 
   $count ++;
 
  }


} #syntax error here

Comment: Don't post code in comments, it's completely unreadable. Check the edit I made, it might not be exactly what you have.

Comment: Sorry I am new here. Yes it's not. it's part of much wider problem I am reading the content of arrays from a file. for each loop would be simillar to that

Comment: @user1044326 : If you need to compare files then say so. Comparing arrays like this is akin to sending telegrams in the computer age.

Comment: @Zaid I'm ok with reading in files and assigning content to array. It's just can't figure out how to do the comparison. Wanted to know how to do that part only. I've amended the script. So it's clearer I hope?

Comment: This sounds a lot like the opposite of what `diff` does, except the opposite. If you are on linux/unix, you may be able to find an option to display only identical lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of *blank* here needs to be clarified. Is it an empty string? An `undef`ined value? Whitespace?

I'm assuming any element with no non-whitespace characters as *blank* in the example below, which shows how it could be done with the `each @array` construct:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @a = ( 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', ' ', ' ' );  # Can't use qw/ / 'cos
my @b = ( ' ', 'B', 'C', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'A' );  # it ignores whitespace

my %count;                                      # Store results in a hash

while ( my ( $index, $value ) = each @a ) { # Loop over index & value together

    my $otherValue = $b[$index];            # Get the other value in @b

    next unless $value =~ /\S/ and $otherValue =~ /\S/;  # Skip if 'blank'

    $count{$value}++ if $value eq $otherValue; # Increment counter for that value
}

print "$_ : $count{$_}\n" for keys %count;     # B : 1
                                               # C : 1

# Find out total

use List::Util 'sum';                          # No need to reinvent wheel
print "Sum : ", sum ( values %count ), "\n";   # Sum : 2
```

Comment: If the `keys @array` syntax is flagged as invalid, your Perl version is pre-5.12.0

Comment: @MonteCristo : My bad. Replace `keys` with `each`

Comment: perfect thanks. Can you explain to me why I need to loop over both value and index instead just the value i.e "foreach my $letter (@a)"?

Answer (score 2):

For your problem as stated, I'd use something like this:

```
$happened += $a[$_] eq $b[$_] for 0 .. $#a;
```

To disregard empty elements, you can check for `defined($a[$_])` and `length($a[$_])` as well.

However,

```
qw/ B B C       A /
```

is the same as `qw/B B C A/`, so no empty elements are introduced. Also, your example for the *same* element shows different elements at different positions.